# Error Handling in Slim Framework Custom Middleware

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to handle errors in slim framework custom middle ware but dont know how to do this like in my code i am doing that if the request is not of four specific types then through an error that i want to handel in errorHandler with appropriate message and status but currently this code is just returning the status in postman with a blank screen in response body. I am not very much familiar with SLIM. Thanks in advance

```
<?php 

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use \Slim\App;

$c = new \Slim\Container();

$c['notAllowedHandler'] = function ($c) { 
    return function ($request, $response, $methods) use ($c) {
        return $c['response']
            ->withStatus(405)
            ->withHeader('Allow', implode(', ', $methods))
            ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
        ->write(json_encode(array("c_status"=>"405","message"=>"Bad Request")));
    };
};

$c['notFoundHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function ($request, $response) use ($c) {
        return $c['response']
            ->withStatus(404)
            ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
        ->write(json_encode(array("c_status"=>"404","message"=>"Not Found")));
    };
};


$c['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) {
        $data = [
            'c_status' => $response->getStatus(),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage()
        ];
        return $container->get('response')->withStatus($response->getStatus())
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->write(json_encode($data));
    };
};

$app = new App($c);

$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    if($request->isGet() || $request->isPost() || $request->isPut() || $request->isDelete()){
        $response = $next($request, $response);
    }else{
        $response = $response->withStatus(403);
    }
    return $response;
});

require 'API/routes.php';
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Throw an exception:

```php
$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    if($request->isGet() || $request->isPost() || $request->isPut() || $request->isDelete()){
        $response = $next($request, $response);
    }else{
        throw new \Exception("Forbidden", 403);
    }
    return $response;
})
```